# Is that any way to alter the sqlite table

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I was create the SQLite database in Chrome extension,after that i want to modify the table column value in xcode,that is returns an error.

> Error:the table has the no column value.

NOTE:I used the following code to alter the table,

```
[instance.database executeQuery:@"ALTER TABLE studentInfo ADD COLUMN l3 TEXT"];
```

Comment: You want to modify it in Xcode?  What does that mean?  Also what framework does `executeQuery:` belong to?

Comment: yes i want to modify,i think you are not getting my point.i used the FMDB framework

Comment: And did you write the error text "the table has the no column value"?  I ask as there is no reference to that text anywhere on the internet apart from this question.  If so you need to find the actual error text from the database (I don't know how that's done in FMDB as I don't use it).

Comment: Explain it clearly

Comment: Actually i want insert data in database,and i create the Database in Browser that file downloaded and i was added that file in my xcode,after that i used to fmdb code to insert the data,in my case if i want to add the any other new columns in xcode that was given an error.that was i mentioned.

Comment: Well you need to obtain the exact error text and I don't see what that error message means.  I assume you've copied the database file from the app bundle into the documents folder before attempting to write to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly alter table by SQlite manager applying into SQL query.

Find a path for your database and then open it and Edit with SQLite manager:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

    do {
        let documentsURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        print(documentsURL)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```